# Routes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know for what reason my app does'nt respond to any POST requests which is a non-REST url.

Below is my routes.rb file.

```
  constraints(Subdomain) do
    resources :invitations

    resources :settings, :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
    scope "/settings" do
      get "/departments" => "settings#departments"
      get "/job_types" => "settings#job_types"
      get "/industries" => "settings#industries"
      get "/functional_areas" => "settings#functional_areas"
      get "/managers" => "settings#managers"
      get "/hrs_responsible" => "settings#hrs_responsible"
      get "/welcome_text" => "settings#welcome_text"
      post "/save_welcome_text" => "settings#save_welcome_text" <-------
    end
  end
```

In my view file, I have

```
=form_for(@setting), :url => "/settings/save_welcome_text", :method => :post do |f|
  - All the form fields here.
  - f.submit "Save"
```

This gist contains the generated HTML, and the respective server log.
https://gist.github.com/943984

When I hit submit, I see "Routing error" that no such route exists. From the server logs I can sniff that the request is sent as a POST request.
However, if I change it to "match" from "post" in routes.rb file, this works. All the GET requests work fine. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: why do you think it isn't work? Show how you are trying to call it. show your links

Comment: Well, I have a "form_for(@setting), :url => "/settings/save_welcome_text", :method => :post", It throws me an error that no route exist.

Comment: Look into sources and show me "<form>" tag

Comment: Check this,https://gist.github.com/943984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify your `method` in `html` block

```
=form_for(@setting), :url => "/settings/save_welcome_text", :html => { :method => :post } do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the methods get and post in your routes.rb is from what I understand only available for member or collection routes inside a resources block.

When you do it otherwise you have to use match and if you only want to make it available for post then you can specify it like this:

```
match "/save_welcome_text" => "settings#save_welcome_text", :via => :post
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I checked with your above above suggestion and still throws me an error. When I use `match "/save_welcome_text" => "settings#save_welcome_text"`, it works. But it matches to all requests which I dont want to, I want it to take only a POST request.

Comment: Are you sure the request is really submitted through post? If you check the logs from when you did not have the :via syntax, does it say it is post? Did you change the form_for like fl00r suggested?